# Please help me on this topic of division.

Tags: arithmetic

What type of division is this? And what is the procedure to solve this? And also which number is supposed to be the answer of the given problem?

[image: division]

Comment: This is [Long Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) and is a technique commonly taught to be used to perform arithmetic division of larger numbers whose answers are more than one or two digits long.  The arithmetic operation being performed here is to find the result of $\dfrac{47072}{67}$ and the answer is $702$

Comment: If the answer is 702 then why we keep solving it even after getting number 702 as a quotient???

Comment: Then perhaps the question wasn't to get the quotient but instead to get the remainder, or rather to get both the quotient and the remainder.

Comment: @JMoravitz The answer is $702$, but the result is $702\frac{38}{67}$ hence the answer is wrong... or it is an answer to some other question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an application of the Euclidean Algorithm to find the greatest common factor of $47072$ and $67$.

One has successively:

$47072 = 67\cdot 702 + 38$

$67=38\cdot 1 + 29$

$38=29\cdot 1+9$

$29=9\cdot 3 + 2$

$9=2\cdot 4+1$

$2=1\cdot 2+0$

Then $\gcd(47072,67)$ is the last nonzero remainder in this process. That is $\gcd(47072,67) = 1$.